# Enlarge a matrix and fill in zeros

Tags: matrix

Suppose I have a dynamically generated 4-dimensional matrix `L` in the shape `shape={d1, d2,d3,d4}`, and `d = Max[shape]`. I want to enlarge `L` to `XL` in the shape `{d,d,d,d}`, filling zeros into new entries.

I wonder what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: When you say `shape = {d1, d2, d3, d4}` do you mean that `Dimensions[L]` would return `{d1, d2, d3, d4}`?  And where would you imagine the original elements of `L` being in `XL`? At the beginning? In the middle?

Comment: Take a look at `ArrayPad`.

Comment: @JasonB: Yes I mean `Dimensions` (I was using `numpy` words when typing). I want to keep the indices of original elements, therefore `XL[[2,2,1,1]] = X[[ 2,2,1,1 ]]`.

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to flesh out what Kuba suggested,

```
oldarray = Array[x[#1, #2, #3, #4] &, {4, 3, 2, 3}];
d = Max@Dimensions@oldarray;
newarray = ArrayPad[oldarray, {0, #} & /@ (d - Dimensions@oldarray)];
Dimensions @ oldarray
Dimensions @ newarray
oldarray // MatrixForm
newarray // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `SparseArray` which has the added advantage of being more memory efficient for many-dimensional arrays.

```
SparseArray[x, Table[Max[Dimensions[x]], {Length[Dimensions[x]]}]]
```

Simply use `Normal` to get the full form of the array.